# JMeter OAuth Bearer Tokens and Role Based Access

Tags: authentication, jmeter, azure-active-directory

I'm new to JMeter and researching authentication tokens as the system I'm testing requires Azure AD login. I've managed to generate an access token but receiving 401 unauthorized error on the HTTP request.

The thing that's confusing me is the system has role based privileges, e.g. a user account would be assigned to a specific role group. However, as the token is generated without username/password input, what access levels is it assigned? Or do I need a different authentication method?

Hopefully that makes sense as this is all new to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think at some point you're providing your credentials but instead of sending them to your application you're sending them to Azure AD.

Given you receive [HTTP 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) I don't think you properly managed to "generate an access token" or you're using it incorrectly.

Ensure that the token is not recorded/hard-coded and it has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter). Then cross-check the requests which JMeter is making with the ones from the "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools). The requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

With regards to roles/groups membership - [authentication != authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/identity-fundamentals/authentication-and-authorization), authentication is the ability to access the system and authorization is what permissions do you have there and this question you should address to your application developers as we don't know what information does token have and how users from Azure AD are mapped in your application

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out why the error is happening now.
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience '1bc7621-6d9f-429d-9b7f-f0f1a4f463f9' is invalid"

It is setting the "audience" claim as the client_id of the application. According to the below, this is only correct for an id_token, not an access_token.

"Identifies the intended recipient of the token. In id_tokens, the audience is your app's Application ID, assigned to your app in the Azure portal. Your app should validate this value, and reject the token if the value does not match"

I fixed this by including the "scope ID" from my application and this is now correctly setting the audience claim.